# Getting element name inside html using cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

New to front end stuff. I am having trouble getting element inside html using cheerio. Please see below what I am trying. I looked other posts, they help to understand how cheerio works but not this.

My goal is to get value ex. I want to get value 67% from `<td class="ctr2">67%</td>`. I am getting undefined. This tag `td class="ctr2"` appears multiple times but I want from first only.

I have been trying for quiet some time now. I get `undefined` using cheerio. What is that I am missing?

```
<tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td class="bar">966 of 2,945</td>
                    <td class="ctr2">67%</td>
                    <td class="bar">56 of 168</td>
                    <td class="ctr2">66%</td>
                    <td class="ctr1">72</td>
                    <td class="ctr2">224</td>
                    <td class="ctr1">167</td>
                    <td class="ctr2">580</td>
                    <td class="ctr1">31</td>
                    <td class="ctr2">140</td>
                    <td class="ctr1">0</td>
                    <td class="ctr2">17</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
```

I am trying below using cheerio in node.js

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

const demo= cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('sample123.html'))
console.log(demo('#ctr2'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems with your code:

1. `#ctr2` is a selector for an element with `id="cntr2"`.  You don't have any `id` values in your HTML.  Instead, you need to use `".ctr2"` if you want to select items with that class name.
2. Your HTML is incomplete as there is no `<table>` and `</table>` surrounding it.

If you fix those two things and run this code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('sample123.html'))
$('.ctr2').each((index, element) => {
    console.log($(element).text());    
});
```

Then, it will generate this output:

```
67%
66%
224
580
140
17
```

---

If you only want the first `.cntr2` item, you can use `.first()` on the selector results like this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

const $ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('sample123.html'))
console.log($('.ctr2').first().text());
```

Which will generate this output:

```
67%
```